# Connect to a public node with web3js

Tags: web3js, nodes, enode

Is it possible to connect the nodes that are listed on [ethernodes.org](https://www.ethernodes.org/nodes)

I chose one of the listed nodes and try to connect with web3 but I get `connection not open on send()` error.

```js
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider("wss://185.117.74.46:48346"))

const getBlockNumber = async() => {
    try{
        const r = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
        console.log(r)
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
getBlockNumber()
```

*Is there any way to connect a public node?*

Comment: Have you heard of infura? Does it fit for you?

Comment: Yes I know infura, etherscan but I don't want to use them.

Comment: The list contains p2p clients they likely do not have rpc nor ws enabled.

Comment: So that means without running a node or using a third-party service like infura is not possible to communicate with ethereum network?

Answer (score -1):

Click on the identifier at Ethernodes to get enode information about a node :

```
enode://00204ddd71303b097e54d8f4e3b45dfd8e31b3ff68ef5973089ae5f9c33ae5787cfc28bfa4fb094a34f563b960adb709efecce0f0cedabe22611bc039b73f799@185.117.74.46:48346
```

Version 2 of Web3 provides an addPeer method

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0-alpha/web3-eth-admin.html#addpeer

Comment: I think he is using web3 as a client, not in a node.